# EmailComposer in Phonegap is not working

Tags: java, javascript, iphone, html, cordova

I have set up plugin from github and do not have any compile time error.
When my code is excuted like below.

window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposer("From Dhaara","Hi we are for you.", "neil.kk@gmail.com", "gvr.k@intelligaia.com", "neil.kk@gmail.com",false);

I got Error below ::

ERROR: Plugin 'EmailComposer' not found, or is not a PGPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in PhoneGap.plist.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: I have found its solution. I did install (example) another plugin like sending SMS, and saw its setting in xcode. I found I was making wrong setting in xcode.

Answer (score 2):

In PhoneGap.plist add:

```
<key>Plugins</key>
<dict>
    <key>EmailComposer</key>
    <string>EmailComposer</string>
</dict>
```